# How to export a namespace with another name in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Let's say my Typescript code uses a third-party namespace `Foo`.

I want to write some utility functions for this module inside an `Utility.Foo` module.

The problem is that the original `Foo` would be hidden to functions defined inside `Utility.Foo`.

In order to work around that, I want to write something like the following:

```typescript
namespace Utility {

  namespace _Foo {
    export function bar() {
      return Foo.x;
    }
  }

  export {_Foo as Foo};

}
```

and it would be transpiled in ES3 into

```javascript
var Utility;
(function (Utility) {

  var _Foo;
  (function (_Foo) {
    _Foo.bar = function () {
        return Foo.x;
    };
  })(_Foo || (_Foo = {}));

  Utility.Foo = _Foo;

})(Utility || (Utility = {}));
```

Using the code above, I'm getting the error

> TS1194: Export declarations are not permitted in a namespace

Why do I get this error?

What is the proper way to achieve that (if any)?

**EDIT**

As I commented in [Paleo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36919839/1160770), if I define my utility functions directly into `Utility.Foo`, the original `Foo` module is effectively hidden.

To understand why, let's look at the following Typescript code:

```typescript
var Foo = { x : 42 };
namespace Utility {
  export namespace Foo {
    export function bar() {
      return Foo.x;
    }
  }
}
```

It is transpiled to ES3 like this:

```
var Foo = { x: 42 };
var Utility;
(function (Utility) {
    var Foo;
    (function (Foo) {
        function bar() {
            return Foo.x;
        }
        Foo.bar = bar;
    })(Foo = Utility.Foo || (Utility.Foo = {}));
})(Utility || (Utility = {}));
```

If we look at how the Utility.Foo module is built, we can see that the `Foo` accessible from the `bar` function is in fact `Utility.Foo = {}`. So `bar` returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the original value in a variable `FooOrig`:

```
var Foo = { x: 42 };

const FooOrig = Foo;
namespace Utility {
  export namespace Foo {
    export function bar() {
      return FooOrig.x;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: When I call `Utility.Foo.bar`, it returns `undefined`. When putting a breakpoint in `Utility.Foo.bar`, I can see that `Foo` is overriden. Here is a [link](http://pastebin.com/8E75xqii) to the transpiled JS. You can see that the original `Foo` module is hidden by the local `Foo`, which is in fact `Utility.Foo = {}`.

Comment: @Antoine, Sorry, I thunk the original `Foo` was in a namespace `Utility`, too. I edited.

Comment: Thank you I'll do that. :) By the way, do you know why I can't use `export { _Foo as Foo}`?

Comment: The syntax `export { as }` is a part of the ES6 modules syntax, it doesn't apply to IIFE/namespaces. TypeScript could implement it on namespaces, but namespaces are not a best practice anymore, therefore, I think we shouldn't expect new features on namespaces.